# How to implement a notification popup with sound in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

How to implement a notification popup with sound in chrome extension.

Just like the [**Checker Plus for Gmail**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj?hl=en)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following code as a reference for playing sound in desktop notifications, it uses `<audio>` tag in conjunction with `Desktop Notifications`.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Registered notification permissions and background page with manifest file.

```
{
    "name": "Notification with Audio",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917531/how-to-implement-a-notification-popup-with-sound-in-chrome-extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Created a notification page from background application.

```
// create a HTML notification:
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
    'notification.html' // html url - can be relative
);

// Then show the notification.
notification.show();
```

#### notification.html

Playing some random songs

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Some Nice Text While Playing Song.. </p>
        <audio autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

## References

- [Notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html)

Comment: `createHTMLNotification` has been deprecated - @Free's answer below is now the correct one.

Answer (score 34):

I think that `createHTMLNotification` has been deprecated since the accepted answer was written.  For anyone happening upon this thread now, here's a method that works as of January 2014 assuming that you have `notifications` permissions in your manifest:

**background.js**

```
createNotification();
audioNotification();

function audioNotification(){
    var yourSound = new Audio('yourSound.mp3');
    yourSound.play();
}

function createNotification(){
    var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your message",iconUrl: "your_icon.png"}
    chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

    //include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},5000);
}
```

The general idea here is just that you'll send out the regular notification and then just use a normal JavaScript method for playing a sound immediately on the heels of the notification's creation.  Of course there are other ways to do it and to organize it, but I think this is pretty clear and very easy to implement in most cases.